# Resourceful routes, but with the #create action using GET instead of POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

While it's generally against our design principles, we need to have a controller execute it's `#create` action on a GET request (it's part of a workflow that involves a series of redirects for an external service).  Does anybody know what the intended way to do this is?  I don't really want to step outside of the resourceful routing framework provided by the Rails routes.  We don't need the `#index` action that would usually respond to that GET request.

I found (surprisingly) that this works, but I don't know if it's intended, or if we'd be exploiting a bug in Rails and risking breakage later down the line:

```
resources :agreements, :except => [:index, :create] do
  get :create, :on => :collection
end
```

If that `get :create` was `get :something`, we'd have had a route like

```
Helper:  something_agreement_path
Request: GET /agreements/:agreement_id/something
Action:  agreements#something
```

But Rails actually generates what we want:

```
Helper:  agreements_path
Request: GET /agreements
Action:  agreements#create
```

Bug, or feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might not be for the latest routing code, but this link has a ton of information about Rails routing. In section 2.3 it covers how the RESTful routes get built.

[Rails Routing from the Inside Out](http://railsguts.com/routing_inside_out.html)

If I was to guess by what I read briefly there.  The default REST actions are manually assigned to a specific route. So when you change the create action to use GET it has some sort of record(hash of routes) that it has already created before creating a new one.

So to answer your question, I assume that this behavior is based on the internal workings of the routing code for Rails. I would assume that it is always possible that this could change at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read over this.  I figured it was down to the *implementation*, which is what worries me... if it's not the intended *behaviour*, then this will break at some point.  Maybe I should just define a different action other than `#create`; I'm now just curious if there is an intended approach to changing the HTTP verb used for each action :)  We can change the path, but seemingly not the verb.